# React - route overrides current url

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple react website with some transitions between sites. It works fine but when I refresh website it doesn't work anymore as the url do not match.

I mean - for example inital url is `user.github.io/app` and when I proceed to `pageOne` the expected url should be `user.github.io/app/pageOne` but the url is just `user.github.io/pageOne`. I've tried `HashRouter` with `basename` but to be honest im quite new to React and I do not understand it. HashRouter gives me this strange `/#/` which doesn't look to good on a webiste. Any quick way to fix it?

Comment: <Route path={`/app/:pageid`} component={page}/> try like this

Comment: Can you provide the component code of your `Router` and `Route`s?

Comment: @Rameshkumar I have added a reply to my post with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have asked for code, so here it is (can't post comments that long)

```
{transitions.map(({ item, props, key }) => (
<animated.div key={key} style={props}>
    <Switch location={item}>
        <Route path="/react-portfolio" component={PageOne} />
        <Route path="*/pathfinding" component={PageOne} />
        <Route path="*/easing" component={PageTwo} />
        <Route path="*/drinks" component={PageThree} />
    </Switch>
</animated.div>
```

This is the example page transition from `Spring` docs. There is no router to be honest. Here is the one link code (rest is the same)

```
<NavLink to="/pathfinding" className="nav-item nav-link" activeClassName="nav-item nav-link active">
Pathfinding
```